# How can you translate "blues for yesterday"?

Tags: traducción, orden-de-palabras

Well, I'm trying to translate:

> I got the blues for yesterday

My intuition tells me that the closest translation to Spanish would be:

> Tuve los Blues de ayer

Is this correct? Or is there a better way to translate such phrase?

Comment: Can you confirm what you mean by "I got the blues for yesterday"? By " I got" do you mean "I possess" or "I acquired", and by blues do you mean a military uniform, the musical style, blue jeans? Or do you mean that you yearn nostalgically for yesterday/the past? It is not clear in your attempt which you intended.

Comment: It is a extract of the lyrics of a song, which is called "blues for yesterday".

Comment: I'm not very confident about it, but [an entry in the urban dictionary](http://es.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=i+got+the+blues) suggests "I got the blues" could mean "I got the same feeling like when singing blues".

Comment: Here is a link to the lyrics of [Blues for Yesterday, by
Louis Armstrong](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Louis-Armstrong/Blues-for-Yesterday)

Comment: Thanks Diego. That is the song! I should have posted the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a literal translation but the closest attempt to put it into Spanish that I can think of would be:

> Tengo nostalgia del ayer.

where `el ayer` refers to the past times in general as that is the purpose of the original English lyrics of the song you are trying to translate.

Comment: +1. Excelente respuesta. "Blues" podría ser traducido también como _tristeza_, _melancolía_, etc. pero _nostalgia_ es el concepto que mejor se adapta a este contexto.